# Open file into Datagrid - Binary formatter

Tags: c#, file-io, datagridview

I would like to read a text file and display the data in the datagrid using c#.

I have used the following code but keep getting an error

```
Stream streamOpen = File.Open(openfile, FileMode.Open);
BinaryFormatter Bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
AddressBook loaded = (AddressBook)Bformatter.Deserialize(streamOpen);
streamOpen.Close();
return loaded;
```

The error I keep getting is

> SerializationException was unhandled - input stream is not a valid binary format.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Following the feedback below I have no longer used the binary formatter but stream reader

```
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"f:\People.txt", FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
            {

                var myString = sr.ReadToEnd();
                return;

            }
        }
```

In order for the code to run I need to include a return line. I want to information that is read to be returned to the Person Bindinglist but displayed in the DataGridView. How would i do this???

Comment: Is your text file a binary file?

Comment: No, its a  normal text file. How else can I get the file to read the text in the file?

Comment: What are the contents of the file? Has it been built by serializing an `AddressBook` object? If so, could you provide your serialization code?